# PHP regex - how can I separate zip and cityname?

Tags: php, regex

How can I separate this data:

```
12345 cityname
54321 anothercityname
```

I tried this regex: `/(\d{5}?),\s*([^,]+)/`

but it doesn't work.

Comment: There is no comma in your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined a `,` in your regex after \d{5} but it is not there in your string.So it will not match.make it optional by adding `?` to it.

See the improved one for your needs

http://regex101.com/r/nG1gU7/8

Comment: what's the meaning of `\d{5}?`?

Comment: you ned to put `?` outside the capturing group. ie, it would be `(\d{5})?` see http://regex101.com/r/nG1gU7/9 and more improved http://regex101.com/r/nG1gU7/10

Answer (score 0):

I think you will seperate your data to zip and city? Then its easier to explode it.

```
$sep = explode(' ', $string);
$zip = $sep[0];
$city = $sep[1];
```

the mistake in your regex is that you have a comma in it.

```
/(\d{5}?),\s*([^,]+)/
```

between your digits and your string. But you have no comma in your string. Make them optional with a `?`
something like this:

```
/(\d{5}?),?\s*([^,]+)/
```